# Truncate Float value up to two decimal point in java

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

```
DecimalFormat hisFormat = new DecimalFormat("########.##");
hisFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

Float x=12345678.12345f;
System.out.println("Float Value " + hisFormat.format(x));
```

Above code print "Float Value" as 12345678
I need 12345678.12

How can I get my result? Please let me know.

Comment: Multiply your number by 100. Round it. Divide by 100 and then print it.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen That's the [wrong way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java#comment17119801_153753).

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Floating-point numbers are stored in base-2, not base-10, so the multiplication introduces rounding errors which often produces an incorrect result.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate. The reason the value is printing as `12345678` is because `float`s can't hold 13 significant digits of precision. If `x` was `5678.1234`, you would indeed see `5678.12` printed out. You should use a `double` if you need more than 8 or so significant digits of precision.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen For proof that it's wrong see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421).

Comment: @GriffeyDog Agreed. Also the OP is already using a  decimal radix, which is what all the correct answers in the alleged duplicate recommend. Reopened. However it is certainly a duplicate of some other question involving invalid `float` ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Double` other than `Float`, or you will lose precision

```
DecimalFormat hisFormat = new DecimalFormat("######.##");
hisFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
Double x = 12345678.12345;
System.out.println("Float Value " + hisFormat.format(x));
```

Use `Float` the result is 12345678

Use `Double` the result is 12345678.12

Comment: Per my requirement, I am going to get Float value only.